# Issue with lmodern in authblk: italics?

Tags: authblk, lmodern

I want to use `lmodern` fonts with `authblk` package, and I want to set the author and affiliation lines in `\scshape` and `\itshape` respectively. However, it gives me slanted letters in affiliation.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[]{authblk}
\renewcommand\Authfont{\scshape}
\renewcommand\Affilfont{\itshape\small}

\title{The Title}
\author{First Author}
\affil{Some University}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

Hello {\itshape world}!

\end{document}
```

which results in:

[image: output1]

I get slanted letters on affiliation. Disabling `lmodern` gives me regular italic characters:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

%\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[]{authblk}
\renewcommand\Authfont{\scshape}
\renewcommand\Affilfont{\itshape\small}

\title{The Title}
\author{First Author}
\affil{Some University}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

Hello {\itshape world}!

\end{document}
```

[image: output2]

Weirdly, if I disable renewing of `Authfont` only while `lmodern` is still loaded, I get italic letters on affiliation:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[]{authblk}
%\renewcommand\Authfont{\scshape}
\renewcommand\Affilfont{\itshape\small}

\title{The Title}
\author{First Author}
\affil{Some University}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

Hello {\itshape world}!

\end{document}
```

gives me

[image: output3]

What's happening here? Note that the italics show properly in the main text in all cases. Is this issue related to the way `authblk` loads the font shapes? I've tested this on both TeXLive 2022 and 2023.

**EDIT**

Here is the log from Texifier (for macOS) when `\normalshape` is used within `\Affilfont` definition:

```
This is TexpadTeX (based on TeX Version 3.14159265 with e-TeX extensions) running in extended mode embedded in Texpad 754 (preloaded format=latex 2021.3.29)  9 APR 2023 13:32
**
(manuscript-template.tex
LaTeX2e <2017-04-15>
Babel <3.16> and hyphenation patterns for 84 language(s) loaded.
(article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count79
\c@section=\count80
\c@subsection=\count81
\c@subsubsection=\count82
\c@paragraph=\count83
\c@subparagraph=\count84
\c@figure=\count85
\c@table=\count86
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
) (lmodern.sty
Package: lmodern 2009/10/30 v1.6 Latin Modern Fonts
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/m/n --> OT1/lmr/m/n on input line 22.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `letters' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OML/cmm/m/it --> OML/lmm/m/it on input line 23.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `symbols' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OMS/cmsy/m/n --> OMS/lmsy/m/n on input line 24.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `largesymbols' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OMX/cmex/m/n --> OMX/lmex/m/n on input line 25.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/n --> OT1/lmr/bx/n on input line 26.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `letters' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OML/cmm/b/it --> OML/lmm/b/it on input line 27.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `symbols' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OMS/cmsy/b/n --> OMS/lmsy/b/n on input line 28.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `largesymbols' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OMX/cmex/m/n --> OMX/lmex/m/n on input line 29.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathbf' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/n --> OT1/lmr/bx/n on input line 31.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathsf' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmss/m/n --> OT1/lmss/m/n on input line 32.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathit' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/m/it --> OT1/lmr/m/it on input line 33.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathtt' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmtt/m/n --> OT1/lmtt/m/n on input line 34.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathbf' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/n --> OT1/lmr/bx/n on input line 35.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathsf' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmss/bx/n --> OT1/lmss/bx/n on input line 36.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathit' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/it --> OT1/lmr/bx/it on input line 37.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathtt' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmtt/m/n --> OT1/lmtt/m/n on input line 38.
) (fontenc.sty
Package: fontenc 2017/04/05 v2.0i Standard LaTeX package
(t1enc.def
File: t1enc.def 2017/04/05 v2.0i Standard LaTeX file
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding T1 on input line 48.
)) (inputenc.sty
Package: inputenc 2015/03/17 v1.2c Input encoding file
\inpenc@prehook=\toks14
\inpenc@posthook=\toks15
(utf8.def
File: utf8.def 2017/01/28 v1.1t UTF-8 support for inputenc
Now handling font encoding OML ...
... no UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding OML
Now handling font encoding T1 ...
... processing UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding T1
(t1enc.dfu
File: t1enc.dfu 2017/01/28 v1.1t UTF-8 support for inputenc
   defining Unicode char U+00A0 (decimal 160)
   defining Unicode char U+00A1 (decimal 161)
   defining Unicode char U+00A3 (decimal 163)
...
)
Now handling font encoding OT1 ...
... processing UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding OT1
(ot1enc.dfu
File: ot1enc.dfu 2017/01/28 v1.1t UTF-8 support for inputenc
   defining Unicode char U+00A0 (decimal 160)
   defining Unicode char U+00A1 (decimal 161)
   defining Unicode char U+00A3 (decimal 163)
...
)
Now handling font encoding OMS ...
... processing UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding OMS
(omsenc.dfu
File: omsenc.dfu 2017/01/28 v1.1t UTF-8 support for inputenc
   defining Unicode char U+00A7 (decimal 167)
   defining Unicode char U+00B6 (decimal 182)
   defining Unicode char U+00B7 (decimal 183)
   defining Unicode char U+2020 (decimal 8224)
   defining Unicode char U+2021 (decimal 8225)
   defining Unicode char U+2022 (decimal 8226)
)
Now handling font encoding OMX ...
... no UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding OMX
Now handling font encoding U ...
... no UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding U
   defining Unicode char U+00A9 (decimal 169)
   defining Unicode char U+00AA (decimal 170)
   defining Unicode char U+00AE (decimal 174)
   defining Unicode char U+00BA (decimal 186)
   defining Unicode char U+02C6 (decimal 710)
   defining Unicode char U+02DC (decimal 732)
   defining Unicode char U+200C (decimal 8204)
   defining Unicode char U+2026 (decimal 8230)
   defining Unicode char U+2122 (decimal 8482)
   defining Unicode char U+2423 (decimal 9251)
)) (authblk.sty
Package: authblk 2001/02/27 1.3 (PWD)
\affilsep=\skip43
\@affilsep=\skip44
\c@Maxaffil=\count87
\c@authors=\count88
\c@affil=\count89
)
No file manuscript-template.aux.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 15.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 15.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 15.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 15.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 15.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 15.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 15.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 15.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 15.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 15.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 15.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 15.
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for T1+lmr on input line 15.
(t1lmr.fd
File: t1lmr.fd 2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
)
! Undefined control sequence.
\Affilfont ->\normalshape 
                          \itshape \small 
l.16 \maketitle
               
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

[1

] (manuscript-template.aux) )


This is TexpadTeX (based on TeX Version 3.14159265 with e-TeX extensions) running in extended mode embedded in Texpad 754 (preloaded format=latex 2021.3.29)  9 APR 2023 13:32
**
(manuscript-template.tex
LaTeX2e <2017-04-15>
Babel <3.16> and hyphenation patterns for 84 language(s) loaded.
(article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count79
\c@section=\count80
\c@subsection=\count81
\c@subsubsection=\count82
\c@paragraph=\count83
\c@subparagraph=\count84
\c@figure=\count85
\c@table=\count86
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
) (lmodern.sty
Package: lmodern 2009/10/30 v1.6 Latin Modern Fonts
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/m/n --> OT1/lmr/m/n on input line 22.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `letters' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OML/cmm/m/it --> OML/lmm/m/it on input line 23.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `symbols' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OMS/cmsy/m/n --> OMS/lmsy/m/n on input line 24.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `largesymbols' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OMX/cmex/m/n --> OMX/lmex/m/n on input line 25.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/n --> OT1/lmr/bx/n on input line 26.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `letters' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OML/cmm/b/it --> OML/lmm/b/it on input line 27.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `symbols' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OMS/cmsy/b/n --> OMS/lmsy/b/n on input line 28.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `largesymbols' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OMX/cmex/m/n --> OMX/lmex/m/n on input line 29.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathbf' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/n --> OT1/lmr/bx/n on input line 31.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathsf' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmss/m/n --> OT1/lmss/m/n on input line 32.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathit' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/m/it --> OT1/lmr/m/it on input line 33.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathtt' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmtt/m/n --> OT1/lmtt/m/n on input line 34.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathbf' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/n --> OT1/lmr/bx/n on input line 35.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathsf' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmss/bx/n --> OT1/lmss/bx/n on input line 36.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathit' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/it --> OT1/lmr/bx/it on input line 37.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathtt' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmtt/m/n --> OT1/lmtt/m/n on input line 38.
) (fontenc.sty
Package: fontenc 2017/04/05 v2.0i Standard LaTeX package
(t1enc.def
File: t1enc.def 2017/04/05 v2.0i Standard LaTeX file
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding T1 on input line 48.
)) (inputenc.sty
Package: inputenc 2015/03/17 v1.2c Input encoding file
\inpenc@prehook=\toks14
\inpenc@posthook=\toks15
(utf8.def
File: utf8.def 2017/01/28 v1.1t UTF-8 support for inputenc
Now handling font encoding OML ...
... no UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding OML
Now handling font encoding T1 ...
... processing UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding T1
(t1enc.dfu
File: t1enc.dfu 2017/01/28 v1.1t UTF-8 support for inputenc
   defining Unicode char U+00A0 (decimal 160)
   defining Unicode char U+00A1 (decimal 161)
   defining Unicode char U+00A3 (decimal 163)
...
)
Now handling font encoding OT1 ...
... processing UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding OT1
(ot1enc.dfu
File: ot1enc.dfu 2017/01/28 v1.1t UTF-8 support for inputenc
   defining Unicode char U+00A0 (decimal 160)
   defining Unicode char U+00A1 (decimal 161)
   defining Unicode char U+00A3 (decimal 163)
...
)
Now handling font encoding OMS ...
... processing UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding OMS
(omsenc.dfu
File: omsenc.dfu 2017/01/28 v1.1t UTF-8 support for inputenc
   defining Unicode char U+00A7 (decimal 167)
   defining Unicode char U+00B6 (decimal 182)
   defining Unicode char U+00B7 (decimal 183)
   defining Unicode char U+2020 (decimal 8224)
   defining Unicode char U+2021 (decimal 8225)
   defining Unicode char U+2022 (decimal 8226)
)
Now handling font encoding OMX ...
... no UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding OMX
Now handling font encoding U ...
... no UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding U
   defining Unicode char U+00A9 (decimal 169)
   defining Unicode char U+00AA (decimal 170)
   defining Unicode char U+00AE (decimal 174)
   defining Unicode char U+00BA (decimal 186)
   defining Unicode char U+02C6 (decimal 710)
   defining Unicode char U+02DC (decimal 732)
   defining Unicode char U+200C (decimal 8204)
   defining Unicode char U+2026 (decimal 8230)
   defining Unicode char U+2122 (decimal 8482)
   defining Unicode char U+2423 (decimal 9251)
)) (authblk.sty
Package: authblk 2001/02/27 1.3 (PWD)
\affilsep=\skip43
\@affilsep=\skip44
\c@Maxaffil=\count87
\c@authors=\count88
\c@affil=\count89
) (manuscript-template.aux)
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 15.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 15.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 15.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 15.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 15.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 15.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 15.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 15.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 15.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 15.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 15.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 15.
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for T1+lmr on input line 15.
(t1lmr.fd
File: t1lmr.fd 2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
)
! Undefined control sequence.
\Affilfont ->\normalshape 
                          \itshape \small 
l.16 \maketitle
               
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

[1

] (manuscript-template.aux) )


This is TexpadTeX (based on TeX Version 3.14159265 with e-TeX extensions) running in extended mode embedded in Texpad 754 (preloaded format=latex 2021.3.29)  9 APR 2023 13:32
**
(manuscript-template.tex
LaTeX2e <2017-04-15>
Babel <3.16> and hyphenation patterns for 84 language(s) loaded.
(article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count79
\c@section=\count80
\c@subsection=\count81
\c@subsubsection=\count82
\c@paragraph=\count83
\c@subparagraph=\count84
\c@figure=\count85
\c@table=\count86
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
) (lmodern.sty
Package: lmodern 2009/10/30 v1.6 Latin Modern Fonts
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/m/n --> OT1/lmr/m/n on input line 22.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `letters' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OML/cmm/m/it --> OML/lmm/m/it on input line 23.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `symbols' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OMS/cmsy/m/n --> OMS/lmsy/m/n on input line 24.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `largesymbols' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OMX/cmex/m/n --> OMX/lmex/m/n on input line 25.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/n --> OT1/lmr/bx/n on input line 26.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `letters' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OML/cmm/b/it --> OML/lmm/b/it on input line 27.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `symbols' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OMS/cmsy/b/n --> OMS/lmsy/b/n on input line 28.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `largesymbols' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OMX/cmex/m/n --> OMX/lmex/m/n on input line 29.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathbf' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/n --> OT1/lmr/bx/n on input line 31.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathsf' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmss/m/n --> OT1/lmss/m/n on input line 32.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathit' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/m/it --> OT1/lmr/m/it on input line 33.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathtt' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmtt/m/n --> OT1/lmtt/m/n on input line 34.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathbf' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/n --> OT1/lmr/bx/n on input line 35.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathsf' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmss/bx/n --> OT1/lmss/bx/n on input line 36.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathit' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/it --> OT1/lmr/bx/it on input line 37.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathtt' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmtt/m/n --> OT1/lmtt/m/n on input line 38.
) (fontenc.sty
Package: fontenc 2017/04/05 v2.0i Standard LaTeX package
(t1enc.def
File: t1enc.def 2017/04/05 v2.0i Standard LaTeX file
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding T1 on input line 48.
)) (inputenc.sty
Package: inputenc 2015/03/17 v1.2c Input encoding file
\inpenc@prehook=\toks14
\inpenc@posthook=\toks15
(utf8.def
File: utf8.def 2017/01/28 v1.1t UTF-8 support for inputenc
Now handling font encoding OML ...
... no UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding OML
Now handling font encoding T1 ...
... processing UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding T1
(t1enc.dfu
File: t1enc.dfu 2017/01/28 v1.1t UTF-8 support for inputenc
   defining Unicode char U+00A0 (decimal 160)
   defining Unicode char U+00A1 (decimal 161)
   defining Unicode char U+00A3 (decimal 163)
...
)
Now handling font encoding OT1 ...
... processing UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding OT1
(ot1enc.dfu
File: ot1enc.dfu 2017/01/28 v1.1t UTF-8 support for inputenc
   defining Unicode char U+00A0 (decimal 160)
   defining Unicode char U+00A1 (decimal 161)
   defining Unicode char U+00A3 (decimal 163)
...
)
Now handling font encoding OMS ...
... processing UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding OMS
(omsenc.dfu
File: omsenc.dfu 2017/01/28 v1.1t UTF-8 support for inputenc
   defining Unicode char U+00A7 (decimal 167)
   defining Unicode char U+00B6 (decimal 182)
   defining Unicode char U+00B7 (decimal 183)
   defining Unicode char U+2020 (decimal 8224)
   defining Unicode char U+2021 (decimal 8225)
   defining Unicode char U+2022 (decimal 8226)
)
Now handling font encoding OMX ...
... no UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding OMX
Now handling font encoding U ...
... no UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding U
   defining Unicode char U+00A9 (decimal 169)
   defining Unicode char U+00AA (decimal 170)
   defining Unicode char U+00AE (decimal 174)
   defining Unicode char U+00BA (decimal 186)
   defining Unicode char U+02C6 (decimal 710)
   defining Unicode char U+02DC (decimal 732)
   defining Unicode char U+200C (decimal 8204)
   defining Unicode char U+2026 (decimal 8230)
   defining Unicode char U+2122 (decimal 8482)
   defining Unicode char U+2423 (decimal 9251)
)) (authblk.sty
Package: authblk 2001/02/27 1.3 (PWD)
\affilsep=\skip43
\@affilsep=\skip44
\c@Maxaffil=\count87
\c@authors=\count88
\c@affil=\count89
) (manuscript-template.aux)
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 15.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 15.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 15.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 15.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 15.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 15.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 15.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 15.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 15.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 15.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 15.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 15.
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for T1+lmr on input line 15.
(t1lmr.fd
File: t1lmr.fd 2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
)
! Undefined control sequence.
\Affilfont ->\normalshape 
                          \itshape \small 
l.16 \maketitle
               
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

[1

] (manuscript-template.aux) )
```

(I had to remove many `defining Unicode char ...` lines as the log was too long.)

Answer (score 1):

The `\scshape` from the author seems to be still in effect. You get slanted small caps instead of italic small caps because the font does not have them. You'll find the following message in the .log file:

> Font shape T1/lmr/m/scit undefined(Font) using T1/lmr/m/scsl instead

You can switch back to normal shape at the start of the affiliation:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[]{authblk}
\renewcommand\Authfont{\scshape}
\renewcommand\Affilfont{\normalshape\itshape\small}

\title{The Title}
\author{First Author}
\affil{Some University}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

Hello {\itshape world}!

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Are there any alternatives to using `\normalshape` to revert it back to italics? I use Texifier for Mac, which uses its own engine to produce real-time typesetting. This gives me an error. Relevant section from log:

`LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for T1+lmr on input line 15.`
`(t1lmr.fd`
`File: t1lmr.fd 2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern`
`)`
`! Undefined control sequence.`
`\Affilfont →\normalshape`

Comment: @GorkemAksaray Can you add your full .log file to your question? Please add it as code block so line breaks are preserved.

Comment: I posted the log from Texifier to my question. Thanks

Comment: @GorkemAksaray Your latex version seem rather old. Can you update?

Comment: @GorkemAksaray Can you try if `\renewcommand\Affilfont{\normalfont\itshape\small}` works?

Comment: this works! Thank you so much. About your comment on latex version, are you referring to TexpadTeX log above? Texifier uses its own engine (I don't know which version of LaTeX they are using). I also have TeXLive 2023 installed -- though I prefer using Texifier because of its real-time rendering.

Comment: @GorkemAksaray I have no idea how updating latex in texifier would work, but it uses a two year old latex

Comment: Well I can't really update myself. I think the developers rewrote parts of TeX in C++ to make it run faster (see here: https://www.texifier.com/blog/) a while ago. So they'd need to update their engine to work with the most recent version of LaTeX. I sometimes use my local TeXLive (which is 2023 version now) to compile but then I don't get real-time compilation. That's I want to write my documents in a way that is **also** compatible with Texifier's engine.